# How to filter items that display in a Sitecore Treelist?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have the following content structure in Sitecore:

- Home

  - Products

    - A-E

      - A Sample Product A
      - B Sample Product B
    - F-J
    - K-O

      - L Sample Product L
    - P-T
    - U-Z

In addition each Product has a checkbox field called "Active".  I would like to have a Treelist that lets the user select one or more products - but they should only be allowed to select Products where the Active checkbox is checked.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can achieve what you need using Sitecore query. Check out the [documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf) for exact syntax rules.

Not all field types support Sitecore query though, so you will need to use a field type that does (Multilist). Or you could implement a [custom TreeList field type that works with query](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Custom%20TreeList%20that%20supports%20query.aspx).

Comment: I looked at the link you included for the custom TreeList that supports Sitecore Query.  From looking at the code in the link what that does is supports using Sitecore Query to set the source to a particular single content node.  That's not exactly what I want to do.  What I want to do is set the source for the TreeList to all of the children of a particular node and exclude certain content items from the list.  I don't think I understand exactly how to do that.

Comment: I haven't implemented this, but from what I'm reading, once you've created the custom field type, you should be able to use any query as a data source. Your query will be determining what items appear in your list (ex. query:/[path_to_your_source_item]//*[@your_field_name= 'somevalue']

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the properties `IncludeTemplatesForDisplay` or `IncludeTemplatesForSelection` to keep your TreeList fields clean.

`IncludeTemplatesForDisplay` makes certain only those templates will show up in the TreeList.
`IncludeTemplatesForSelection` allows you to define which templates you can actually select in the TreeList field.

In your case, you could set `IncludeTemplatesForDisplay` the template of your Products item, then the A-E etc. items, and also the actual Products template. If you then select `IncludeTemplatesForSelection` you can make sure the content editors can still only select the actual product item.

Other parameters are `ExcludeTemplatesForSelection`, `DatabaseName`, `ExcludeTemplatesForDisplay`, `IncludeItemsForDisplay`, `ExcludeItemsForDisplay` and `AllowMultipleSelection`.

Do keep in mind that won't allow selections where a checkbox is ticked, but you could consider creating a custom field based on a `TreeList` field, which has the additional property which checks whether the `Active` field is set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a way out of the box to set the datasource of a treelist (or any list based field, for that matter) to a set of Items and filter by the value of their fields.

How about thinking about it differently.

What if you had a mirror of the products section of the tree somewhere else in your tree but, instead of having all products in this mirrored section, you'd have only the products that are active.  The items in this mirrored section would have a drop-link field that maps to the original product in the original section of the tree.  To keep this list up-to-date, you could use a custom action when the original product is saved.  When a product is saved, if the Active checkbox is checked, create an item of type **Mirrored Product** (for example) in the Mirrored Products section of the tree and set the drop-link to the original product.  When a product is saved, if the Active checkbox is not checked, find the Mirrored Product that maps to this product being saved and delete it.

Finally, the datasource for your treelist would be the root of these Mirror Products section of the tree, not the original products themselves.  This way, the options for your treelist would always only ever items that map to products whose Active checkbox was checked.

One thing to keep in mind: when you delete a Mirrored Product, if it's referenced by a treelist, that reference will remain; you'll need to have your code check for null before trying to use a treelist item.